# How do you get an animation callback in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I fade out an image with

```
<img ng-show="visible" src="">

$scope.visible = toggle;

img { -webkit-transition: all 1s; opacity: 1; }
img.ng-hide-add { display:inline !important; }
img.ng-hide { opacity: 0;}
```

but I would like a callback to fire when the fade out is complete. I know in jQuery you can just do `$(foo).on("animationEnd", func);` but I would prefer to do this stricly through AngularJS.

I made a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ecJ9imhnoqTuUdJxxYqA?p=preview) (webkit only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunately not as easy as you'd hope. There's no way to pass an animation end callback to `ng-show`, so instead you have to implement your own show/hide directive and make use of the [`$animate`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/%24animate) service.

I [forked your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KzPPl5gj44Ci4MctFJqL?p=preview) to demonstrate.

This is the directive I made:

```
app.directive("myShow", function($animate){
  return {
    scope:{
      // use & so that this will evaluate expressions.
      toggle: "&myShow"
    },
    link: function( scope, element, attrs ){

      // watch the toggle function
      scope.$watch(scope.toggle, function(newVal, oldVal){

        if(newVal && oldVal != undefined){
          $animate.removeClass(element, 'ng-hide', function(){
            console.log("finished");
          })
        } 

        else {
          $animate.addClass(element,'ng-hide', function(){
            console.log("finished!");
          })
        }

      });
    }
  }
});
```

You can see that you call `$animate`'s `addClass` method with `ng-hide` and you can use the exact same CSS. Using the `$animate` service directly means you can make use of the `doneCallback`.

**PS** this is just to demonstrate `$animate`, I haven't checked whether this initialises properly - you might need to make sure `ng-hide` is correctly on/off when the page loads.